# glDrawElements with Stack Memory

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have two arrays that I declared on the stack in a function, and verified that they both contain the exact same data:

```
/// Rasters the textured quad using the specified parameters.
- (void)privateConfigureRasterWithTexture:(GLuint)theTexture
                          bottomLeftX:(GLfloat)bottomLeftX
                          bottomLeftY:(GLfloat)bottomLeftY
                            topRightX:(GLfloat)topRightX
                            topRightY:(GLfloat)topRightY
{

    const GLfloat texices[] =
      { bottomLeftX, bottomLeftY,   // bottom left corner
        bottomLeftX,   topRightY,   // top left corner
          topRightX,   topRightY,   // top right corner
          topRightX, bottomLeftY }; // bottom right corner

    const GLfloat texices2[] =
      { 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f };

    for(int x=0;x<8;x++)
        if(texices[x] != texices2[x])
        {
            NSLog(@"Mismatch!");
            abort();
        }
```

When I execute the following line of code in (the bottom of) that function

```
glVertexAttribPointer(_attributeTexturedTexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                      2*sizeof(GLfloat), texices2);
```

I get the expected result, however if I instead execute

```
glVertexAttribPointer(_attributeTexturedTexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                      2*sizeof(GLfloat), texices);
```

I get a bad result. I don't get what the difference is.

**Edit: Here is how I'm invoking this function.**

```
[self privateConfigureRasterWithTexture:_atlasTexture1
                            bottomLeftX:0.0f
                            bottomLeftY:0.0f
                              topRightX:1.0f
                              topRightY:1.0f];
```

Comment: What are those variables in texices?

Comment: They are parameters to that function, all with the type GLfloat.

Comment: Where do you invoke glVertexAttribPointer and glDrawZYZ functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I think I've found it (probably at around the exact same time Martins did). It looks like `glVertexAttribPointer` doesn't make a copy of the data until the call to `glDrawElements`. Since my `glDrawElements` is outside of that function, the stack memory was being released (yet for some reason `texices2` remained valid).

I've rewritten the code a bit so that `texices` is heap allocated once when that class is allocated, and just reused over and over again and free'd when the application deallocs.